# @Qualifier not picking up @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) on setting up OAuth authentication in my web application I have just started, I am fairly new to spring and have been scratching my head over as to why the `OAuth2AuthorisationServerConfig` class cannot pick up the bean.

```
@Configuration
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("JL").password("TEST").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean //Here is the bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class OAuth2AuthorisationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")  // here is the qualifier for bean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    ....
}
```

The two classes are in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the OAuth2AuthorisationServerConfig class I had annotated it with @ComponentScan and this seemed to have solved the problem